# Multiple asynchronous tasks in Android App

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have a strange problem. I'm developing an Android app which has 3 independent Async Tasks. When I try to run the app on a quad core phone there is no problem. But if I try to run the app on a dual core phone app crashes. How can I modify my tasks for dual core phones ?

Here is my code

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
```

This is the first async task. The second one is the Parse.com file upload async saveInBackground method.

```
public void startUpload(String fileName) {

        try {
            photoFile = new ParseFile(fileName, scaledData);
            if (isTac) {
                pictures.setPhotoFileTac(photoFile);
            } else if (isCanak) {
                pictures.setPhotoFileCanak(photoFile);
            } else if (isYaprak) {
                pictures.setPhotoFileYaprak(photoFile);
            }


           // pictures.save();// Telefon çekirdeğine göre 2 asenkron methodu desteklemiyor o yüzden sadece save yazılabilir fakat başarılı kontolü SaveCallback' te yakalanamaz.




            pictures.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Buluta yükleme başarılı. " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(pdialog != null)
                        {
                            pdialog.dismiss();//Eğer işlem başarılı ise asenkron sınıfta yaratılan progressbar ı kapat.
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hata" +e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bağlantı Hatası !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

And the third one is the progress bar of upload process.

```
public class AsyncUpload extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(TakePictureActivity.this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... fileNames) {

        return fileNames[0];

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String name) {

        startUpload(name);

        super.onPostExecute(name);

    }

}
```

And there is the code where I initialize upload session. (In if - else condition states the line **new AsyncUpload().execute(fileName);**

```
private void saveScaledPhoto(byte[] data) {

    // Resize photo from camera byte array
    pictureWidth = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width;
    pictureHeight = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().height;
    Bitmap plantImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    Bitmap plantImageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(plantImage, pictureWidth, pictureHeight, false);
    pictureCache = new PictureCache();
    // Override Android default landscape orientation and save portrait
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap rotatedScaledPlantImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(plantImageScaled, 0,
            0, plantImageScaled.getWidth(), plantImageScaled.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    rotatedScaledPlantImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

    scaledData = bos.toByteArray();

    AlertDialog.Builder aDB = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    aDB.setCancelable(false);
    aDB.setTitle("Emin misiniz ?");
    aDB.setMessage("Çektiğiniz resim analizde kullanılacaktır. Devam etmek istiyor musunuz ?.. ");
    aDB.setPositiveButton("Evet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            if (isTac) {

                pictureCache.setByteArrayTac(scaledData);
                isTac = false;
                isCanak = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Taç yaprak görüntüsü alındı.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String currentTimeStamp = getCurrentTimeStamp();
                fileName = "TacYaprak";

                new AsyncUpload().execute(fileName);

            } else if (isCanak) {


                pictureCache.setByteArrayCanak(scaledData);
                isCanak = false;
                isYaprak = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Çanak yaprak görüntüsü alındı.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String currentTimeStamp = getCurrentTimeStamp();
                fileName = "CanakYaprak";

                new AsyncUpload().execute(fileName);
            } else if (isYaprak) {

                String plantTag = "A_Y";
                pictureCache.setByteArrayYaprak(scaledData);
                isYaprak = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ağaç yaprağı görüntüsü alındı.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String currentTimeStamp = getCurrentTimeStamp();
                fileName = "AgacYapragi";

                new AsyncUpload().execute(fileName);
            }

            if (!isTac && !isCanak && !isYaprak) {
                finish();
            }

        }


    });
    aDB.setNegativeButton("Hayır", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = aDB.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Here is the logcat output..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:482)
        at com.altygtsoft.biomatch.TakePictureActivity.saveScaledPhoto(TakePictureActivity.java:202)
        at com.altygtsoft.biomatch.TakePictureActivity.access$000(TakePictureActivity.java:45)
        at com.altygtsoft.biomatch.TakePictureActivity$2$1$2.onPictureTaken(TakePictureActivity.java:147)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:855)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post stacktrace with the error

Comment: Would you also post the line where you are actually executing the AsyncTask?

Comment: Are you getting an out of memory error?

Comment: I've added the lines of where async methods initialize. And here is the logcat output when "Unfortunately bla bla" begins.

Comment: When I use pictures.save() method of parse there is no error on dual and quad phones. But if I use saveInBackground method of parse it will occur this error on dual core phones.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized my idea is too big for a comment so->

What happens if you do the following?

```
//Beware pseudo-code
new AsyncTask<>({
    onPreExecute(){
        //keep your code from before
        ...
    }
    doInBackground(Params... params){ 
        startUpload(params[0], params[1]); //minus the done() function, plus pictures?
    }
    onPostExecute(){
    //As I'm not sure where it fits in, if possible execute done() here.
    }
}).execute(fileName, pictures); //couldn't find the decleration of pictures, so I stole the decleration of independence instead. Also maybe you need to put pictures in there, depending on where it is and how public/static.
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution I've decided to make image processing in another activities and basically I've comment out OpenCV.initAsync line and problem solved for me but my definition of AsyncTask has problems I know but I can't see it for now :)